# Не могу получить данные с COM-порта на Java

Tags: java, com-port

```
public class Buttons {

private static SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1") ;

public static void frame(){
    ButtonFrame frame= new ButtonFrame();//frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//end of the program
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
static class ButtonFrame extends JFrame{
public ButtonFrame(){
    setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH,DEFAULT_HEIGHT);//frame size
    setTitle("Scale");
    ButtonPanel panel=new ButtonPanel();
    add(panel);

}
public static final  int DEFAULT_WIDTH=700;
public static final  int DEFAULT_HEIGHT=250;
}
static class ButtonPanel extends JPanel{// Frame
JTextField textField=new JTextField(20);
JTextArea textArea=new JTextArea(10,50);
public ButtonPanel(){ //constructor of panel add(textField);

    JButton RunButton = new JButton("Пуск"); //create buttons
    JButton StopButton = new JButton("Стоп");
    JButton SaveButton = new JButton("Сохранить");
    JButton CheckPorts = new JButton("Получить список доступных портов");

    add(RunButton); //adding button on a panel
    add(StopButton);
    add(SaveButton);
    add(CheckPorts);

    ButtonActionRun RunAction = new ButtonActionRun();
    ButtonActionStop StopAction = new ButtonActionStop();
    ButtonActionSave SaveAction = new ButtonActionSave();
    ButtonActionCheckPorts CheckAction = new ButtonActionCheckPorts();

    RunButton.addActionListener(RunAction); //set action for buttons
    StopButton.addActionListener(StopAction);
    SaveButton.addActionListener(SaveAction);
    CheckPorts.addActionListener(CheckAction);

    add(textArea);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);

}

private class ButtonActionRun implements ActionListener{
    private SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
    private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    private Date date = new Date();
    private String s = dateFormat.format(date);
    protected String portOpenFail;
    private String fromPort;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){ //Button reaction
        try {
            serialPort.openPort();
            serialPort.setParams(
                    SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            serialPort.setFlowControlMode(
                    SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN |
                    SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_OUT);

            serialPort.addEventListener(new EventListener(), serialPort.MASK_RXCHAR);
            //serialPort.addEventListener(new EventListener());
            serialPort.writeString("R");

        } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            portOpenFail = "Port"+ " " + serialPort.getPortName()+ " " + "not found" + " " + ex;
        }
        try {
            textField.setText(fromPort = serialPort.readString());
            textField.setText(fromPort + s);
            textField.setText(fromPort);
            textArea.append(fromPort + s + "\n");
        } catch (SerialPortException e) {
            textField.setText("No Data from " + serialPort.getPortName());
            textArea.setText("No Data from " + serialPort.getPortName() + "\n");
        }


    }
}

private class ButtonActionStop implements ActionListener{
    private String actionStop;
    private String actionStopFail;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            serialPort.closePort();
            actionStop = "Port Closed!" + serialPort.getPortName();
            textField.setText(actionStop);
            textArea.append(actionStop + "\n");
        } catch (SerialPortException e) {
            actionStopFail = "Port not closed" + " " + serialPort.getPortName();
           textField.setText(actionStopFail);
           textArea.append(actionStopFail + "\n");
        }

    }

}

private class ButtonActionSave implements ActionListener{
    private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    private Date date = new Date();
    private String dateDB = dateFormat.format(date);
    private String actionSave;
    private String dataSavedToDB;
    private String dataNotSavedToDB;
    private String dataReceived;


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            serialPort.addEventListener(new EventListener());
            dataReceived = serialPort.readString();

        } catch (SerialPortException e) {
            textField.setText("Check Serial Port! " + e);
            textArea.setText("Check Serial Port! " + e + "\n");
        }
        try {
            initDB();
            addData(dataReceived, dateDB);

            dataSavedToDB = "Data successfully saved to Data Base!";

            textField.setText(dataSavedToDB + " " + dataReceived + " " + " date:" + dateDB);
            textArea.setText(dataSavedToDB + " " + dataReceived + " " + " date:" + dateDB + "\n");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            dataNotSavedToDB = "Fail to save data!";
            textField.setText(dataNotSavedToDB);
            textArea.setText(dataNotSavedToDB + "\n");
        }

    }

}

private class ButtonActionCheckPorts implements ActionListener{

    private String actionCheck;
    private String portsList;
    private String portName = "COM1";

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();

        if (portNames.length == 0) {
            actionCheck = "There are no serial-ports :(";
            textField.setText(actionCheck);
            textArea.setText(actionCheck + "\n");
            return;
        }

        // Available ports
        actionCheck = "Available com-ports:";
        for (int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
            portsList = portNames[i];
        }

        actionCheck = "Type port name, which you want to use, and press Enter...";
        textField.setText(actionCheck);
        textArea.setText(actionCheck + "\n");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        portName = in.next();

        textField.setText(actionCheck);
        textArea.append(actionCheck + "\n");

        textField.setText(portsList);
        textArea.append(portsList);

    }

}

private class EventListener implements SerialPortEventListener {
    public String receivedData;
    public String noDataFromPort;

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0){
            try {
                receivedData = serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue());
                textField.setText(receivedData);
                textArea.setText(receivedData + "\n");
                serialPort.closePort();
            }
            catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                noDataFromPort = "No data received";
                textField.setText(noDataFromPort + " " + ex);
                textArea.setText(noDataFromPort + " " + ex + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
}
```